# building a game using dart, flutter and flame: rendering the image layer from tiled

Tags: flutter, image, dart, tiled, flame

I'm building a game using the flame game engine. I encountered an issue with the map I built using Tiled - which generates a .tmx file that is called by the code using the following commands:

```
var demoMap = await TiledComponent.load("demoMap.tmx", Vector2(128, 128));
add(demoMap);
mapHeight = 128.0 * demoMap.tileMap.map.height;
mapWidth = 128.0 * demoMap.tileMap.map.width;
final List<TiledObject> obstacles =
    demoMap.tileMap.getLayer<ObjectGroup>('Collisions')!.objects;
for (final TiledObject obstacle in obstacles) {
  add(Obstacle(obstacle));
}
```

these lines will load the Tile layers and object layers. but not the image layer. the background appears black no matter what I do.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. I hope the following 2 methods will help.

1. You can give background to ".tmx" file.
2. Use ParallaxComponent. Here's the code I used on my project.

```dart
class GameBackground extends ParallaxComponent<HorseRiderGame> {
  double velocity = 0.0;

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    Vector2 gameSize = gameRef.size;
    gameSize.y;

    parallax = await gameRef.loadParallax(
      [
        ParallaxImageData('background/sky.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('background/jungle_bg.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('background/trees_bushes.png'),
        ParallaxImageData('background/grasses.png'),
      ],
      repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX,
      baseVelocity: Vector2(velocity, 0.0),
      velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(2, 0.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Then add this class to the FlameGame class.

```dart
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    add(GameBackground());
  }
```